# What is an effective way of segregating dev builds in Crashlytics?

Tags: crashlytics

What is an effective way of segregating dev builds in Crashlytics?

We are currently appending the letter "D" onto our development builds, and then using the "Hidden Versions" feature in the Crashlytics app settings to turn off any versions that have "D" in them. It's a manual step, so it's not great.

It also doesn't work entirely - I still see "D" versions showing up in some Crashlytics UI, like the version adoption box.

What solution has the Crashlytics community decided is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. I'd love to see other's opinions, but we recommend one of two things. If you can - append .debug to the bundle id or package name for your debug builds and then you would have two apps in Fabric and the data would be kept separated out.

An alternate option if you can't do that would be to create two organizations within Fabric and conditionally decide which API key and build secret to use. For example, on iOS, you could change the run script build phase to be:

```
releaseConfig="Release"

if [ "$releaseConfig" = "${CONFIGURATION}" ]; then
    echo "Running Crashlytics Release"
    ./Fabric.framework/run <your__release_api_key_here>
else
    echo "Running Crashlytics Debug"
    ./Fabric.framework/run <your__debug_api_key_here>
fi
```

and then remove the Fabric API key from your info.plist and init Fabric like:

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:<your api key>];
```

and use a variable to reference which key to use.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I didn't get a notification about your reply, but we ended up discovering the first option on our own.