# How do I prevent versions from being generated for app in Crashlytics with Gradle build

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I'd like to have build-time control of whether a build will create a version for my app.  I currently have Crashlytics enabled only for specific Jenkins jobs (in fact, the plugin isn't even applied if it isn't being built by my Release job), and my Jenkins PR job builds both debug and release.

Unfortunately this still seems to cause the feature-branch builds from the PR job to appear in the version list for my app - which clutters up the search bar when I'm trying to filter for recently released versions.

How can I make it so that *nothing* gets sent to the crashlytics servers?  Do I need to segregate the Fabric.with() call so that its not run with in the crashlytics-disabled case?  As opposed to currently, it is run with:

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!enableCrashlytics()).build())
    .build();
Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

Would that be enough?

Note: I have seen this question [What is an effective way of segregating dev builds in Crashlytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765742/what-is-an-effective-way-of-segregating-dev-builds-in-crashlytics) and Mike's response is not feasable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

You need to not initialize Fabric at all. You're init code prevents Crashlytics from being initialized, but not Answers, so data will still be sent.

Alternatively, separate out your builds so that only for production builds does data flow into an organization for your prod builds only and then have all other builds flow into the same app in a different organization. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/alexsinger/2b5b1b7ae2d2fca1ffdb):

```
// The following code allows an app to report Crashlytics crashes separately 
// for release and debug buildTypes when using Gradle. This code should be inserted 
// into the specified locations within your build.gradle (Module:app) file

    // The buildTypes { } block should be inserted inside the android { } block
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.crashlyticsApiSecret = "release api secret"
            ext.crashlyticsApiKey = "release api key"
        }
        debug {
            ext.crashlyticsApiSecret = "debug api secret"
            ext.crashlyticsApiKey = "debug api key"
        }
    }

// The following code can be inserted at the bottom of your build.gradle file
import com.crashlytics.tools.utils.PropertiesUtils

File crashlyticsProperties = new File("${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/fabric.properties")
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantSuffix = variant.name.capitalize()
    def generateResourcesTask = project.tasks.getByName("fabricGenerateResources${variantSuffix}")
    def generatePropertiesTask = task("fabricGenerateProperties${variantSuffix}") << {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        println "...copying apiSecret for ${variant.name}"
        properties.put("apiSecret", variant.buildType.ext.crashlyticsApiSecret)
        println "...copying apiKey for ${variant.name}"
        properties.put("apiKey", variant.buildType.ext.crashlyticsApiKey)
        PropertiesUtils.injectPropertyInFile(crashlyticsProperties, properties, "")
    }
    generateResourcesTask.dependsOn generatePropertiesTask
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Our QA department still uses Release builds for testing, so the separate org for debug won't help that much.  I can refactor so that we don't init Fabric at all though, or maybe having the jenkins job inject the key and secret at build time would let us use the separate org...  Things to try.

Comment: We ended up no initializing Fabric at all, and it's working quite nicely now.  Thanks